# Laravel 5.5: 'Method foreing does not exist' - Error con llave foránea

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, migration

Al seguir los tutoriales del [Blog en Laravel de Rimorsoft Online](https://youtu.be/vyLpqpBiMYw?t=332), he tenido el siguiente problema a la hora de migrar:

*Texto en Consola:*

```
In Macroable.php line 96:
Method foreing does not exist.
```

El archivo de migraciones es:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->increments('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
        //Relacion
        $table->foreing('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}
```

Y la tabla users es la siguiente:

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

*Entorno:*

- Windows 10 Pro Build 1709
- PHP 7.1.11
- Node.js 9.2.0
- npm 5.6
- composer 1.5.6

¿Por qué me da este error?

Answer (score 2):

Habia un error en el codigo, esta es la solucion:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

el error esta en cambiar el foreing por **foreign**